# Fail to connect to OpenVPN server

Tags: openvpn

I setup server-side OpenVPN service based on [this document](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-openvpn-server-on-ubuntu-16-04), it was working fine. Something seems to go wrong today, because I get the following error:

```
Options error: --up script fails with '/etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf': No such process (errno=3)
```

Nothing is changed in the file and it's still these with x attrib set.
The only thing I remember that I did is that I tried to block all clients other than a specific IP. I tried it by UFW. Then I reverted it back by:

```
sudo ufw reset
```

and then added the two allowed ports rules, 1194 and OpenSSH as described in the document.

Now that I see that the file is there and is executable, how can I find what's the problem? It's the only error in the log.